# CodePen Home bootstrap 3 multiple items responsive carousel

Tags: bootstrap, responsive, bootstrap-carousel

Utilizando el siguiente carousel responsivo publicado en codepen, este solo se desplaza de a un solo div por vez, estoy tratando que pase de a 4 divs por cada vez

https://codepen.io/Qvatra/pen/yOvBoM?css-preprocessor=less

Comment: Por favor leer [ask] y [mcve]. Es necesario que el código relevante lo publiques aquí en tu pregunta, un enlace a un sitio externo no es suficiente y se considera de baja calidad. Saludos

Answer (score -1):

**Te mostraré un ejemplo completo de como lo puedes hacer.**

Éste sería el **HTML**:

```
<div class="top-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 active">
                    <img src="assets/img/backgrounds/1.jpg" class="img-fluid 
                     mx-auto d-block" alt="img1">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <img src="assets/img/backgrounds/2.jpg" class="img-fluid 
                     mx-auto d-block" alt="img2">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <img src="assets/img/backgrounds/3.jpg" class="img-fluid 
                     mx-auto d-block" alt="img3">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <img src="assets/img/backgrounds/4.jpg" class="img-fluid 
                     mx-auto d-block" alt="img4">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <img src="assets/img/backgrounds/5.jpg" class="img-fluid 
                     mx-auto d-block" alt="img5">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example" 
             role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example" 
             role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Éste sería el codigo de **JavaScript**

```js
$('#carousel-example').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    /*
        CC 2.0 License Iatek LLC 2018 - Attribution required
    */
    var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var idx = $e.index();
    var itemsPerSlide = 5;
    var totalItems = $('.carousel-item').length;
 
    if (idx >= totalItems-(itemsPerSlide-1)) {
        var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
        for (var i=0; i<it; i++) {
            // append slides to end
            if (e.direction=="left") {
                $('.carousel-item').eq(i).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
            }
            else {
                $('.carousel-item').eq(0).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Y por ultimo los estilos para que sea totalmete responsive:

```
/*
    code by Iatek LLC 2018 - CC 2.0 License - Attribution required
    code customized by Azmind.com
*/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    /* Show 4th slide on md if col-md-4*/
    .carousel-inner .active.col-md-4.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -33.3333%;  /*change this with javascript in the future*/
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* Show 3rd slide on sm if col-sm-6*/
    .carousel-inner .active.col-sm-6.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -50%;  /*change this with javascript in the future*/
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .carousel-item {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    /* show 2 items */
    .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item {
        display: block;
    }
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item {
        transition: none;
    }
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    /* left or forward direction */
    .active.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
    }
    /* farthest right hidden item must be also positioned for animations */
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    /* right or prev direction */
    .active.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
/* MD */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    /* show 3rd of 3 item slide */
    .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        display: block;
    }
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        transition: none;
    }
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    /* left or forward direction */
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
    }
    /* right or prev direction */
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
/* LG */
@media (min-width: 991px) {
    /* show 4th item */
    .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        display: block;
    }
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        transition: none;
    }
    /* Show 5th slide on lg if col-lg-3 */
    .carousel-inner .active.col-lg-3.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -25%;  /*change this with javascript in the future*/
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    /* left or forward direction */
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
    }
    /* right or prev direction //t - previous slide direction last item animation fix */
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

Encontré éste ejemplo en: [Bootstrap 4 Carousel with Multiple Items: How To Create It?](https://azmind.com/bootstrap-carousel-multiple-items/).

Comment: Gracias @BetaM, estoy empezando en stack, trataré de aprender rápido.

Comment: Hay que evitar responder preguntas mal redactadas, ya que las mismas podrían terminar cerradas, lo cual hará que tu publicación sea menos visible. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Enmah4k, quedo bastante mejor de lo que estaba en codepen, pero sigue pasando de a uno

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte @MauricioContreras, me disculpo, estoy empezando en esta plataforma ahora. Estoy aprendiendo.

Comment: Mauricio Contreras la pregunta no está mal redactada, si no comprendes lo que ahi pregunto tenes problemas de comprensión